Splotchy polyurethane finish
We’ve been redoing our hardwood floors and have applied a second coat of polyurethane after screen sanding with 180 grit between the first and second coats. The floors upstairs that received the second coat of poly look like they’re drying fine. The floors in our dining room and kitchen are splotchy all over, almost like a hammered copper pattern. I’ve used the same roller method for application on both sets of floors. The poly is Minwax fast drying oil based satin finish. Any insights on where things might have gone south? The first coat of poly on these floors went down smooth. 

Are your floors flat? Were the floors sanded prior to the first application? This looks like the finish has pooled or there is some residue on the floor that caused the finish to lose its cohesion.

@DelphicOracle flat to an extent- the boards are not bumpy, but there are some areas where floors seem to have a downward slope towards base of cabinets and walls. Floors had been sanded with a drum sander with 60, 80, 100 and 120 grits prior to staining.  No issues with the first coat of poly, which had dried for approximately 13 hours prior to screen sanding before the second coat. Floors were then vacuumed and wiped with a dry microfiber mop.

The finish is still milky. Is this how the polyurethane came out of the can? My best guess is that even though the product was listed as fast dry, there was not enough air circulation in the location to dry completely before the second coat. Spot sand, refinish, and live with the result.

@DelphicOracle I should have specified that the photo is the glare from the overhead light- it best displayed the issue. I appreciate your input!
